# react-native android borderRadius antiAliasing

Tags: react-native, view, antialiasing

How to draw a smooth circle in react-native?

AntiAliasing is disabled in borderRadius rendering.

The only way i found is to use ART.Shape (left)

```
<View style={{
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
  borderRadius: 16,
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: '#2196f3',
}}/>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get a better answer? facing the same issue on tablet displays. Looks good on small devices but not tablet and bigger.